# DCT: Read a list of DCRs

Tags: teamsite, autonomy

I encountered an impediment while attempting to create a DCT that will allow a users to select from a list of existing DCRs. In this case, the DCT allows users to create an "Editor's Pick" list from all available articles.

To accomplish this, I need to create a DCT that can parse all available DCRs for a certain node ("articleHeadline" for example) and return the DCR name as an option value, and the headline as the option text.

I first thought to use FormsAPI, but unless I make all of the DCRs available via HTTP requests, I couldn't find a useful method.

The second attempt was to create a datasource as described in the manual "Teamsite 7.2: Data Capture Development" (pp. 153, 224-225) but I was stymied by my inability to find useful documentation on the subject.

Can anyone point me to documentation that will help to create a DCR-reading dataource or to some other method that will help me to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a list of DCR names in a particular folder to display in a select box by using the browser tag in your Data Capture Template(DCT).

```
<browser initial-dir="templatedata/Student/data" ceiling-dir="templatedata/Student/data" required="f" readonly="f">
```

The above browser tag can read all the DCR names in the templatedata/Student/data folder and will provide you with a drop down box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't solve the problem I face. I am not looking for a list of DCRs names, but rather for the ability to parse the DCRs for a certain node (articleHeadline, for example) and insert the results as options in a select field. The DCR names do not have enough data to allow users to make knowledgeable selections.

Comment: Something similar to what you are looking for can be done by reading information from the DCR's on the teamsite server using the cssdk provided by teamsite with Java.

Comment: Assuming you want to use the list of DCRs and the articleHeadline node value from all the DCRs inside a component, I have prepared the below solution. You can create a Java/.Net class external send the path of the DCR files names. You can read the DCR files inside the class and create Dom4J xml nodes. Hope this helps. Thanks.